# Multiple commands in command prompt using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "cmd /c c:"
```

This line executes perfectly fine. Now I need to enter a text.

For example: `c:\users> "abcd"`

How do I go about it in the already opened cmd prompt.

Answer (score 8):

You must add **&** after each command and change **cmd /c** to **cmd /k**

1. The first command is : **CD /D** c:\
2. The second command is : **Dir**
3. The third command is : **ping 127.0.0.1**

Try like this :

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Command = "cmd /K cd /d c:\ & Dir & ping 127.0.0.1"
oShell.Run Command,1,True
```