# How to run CMD commands one by one in HTA

Tags: cmd, activex, wsh, jscript, hta

I'm trying to run in my HTA file the following Win CMD commands one by one

```
<script>
var WShell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');
WShell.run('cmd /c "cd C:\\Users\\Username\\myFolder && mkdir mySubfolder"');
</script>
```

This code creates a subfolder `mySubfolder` inside of the folder my HTA file is in. But I need to go to the specific folder `C:/Users/Username/myFolder` and to do something inside of the folder for example to create a subfolder, i.e. the second command is dependent on the first one.

How can I do that?

Comment: What variable are you talking about? My question here is about two CMD commands, has no relation to your link about variable and again is not the same as my question about downloading a file

Comment: The variable comment was me mixing up two different questions, my apologies.

Comment: Why not just call it in one go? `mkdir C:\\Users\\Username\\myFolder\\mySubfolder"');`

Comment: It's just an example. Actually I want to run nodejs with HTA something like `cd project && node test.js`

Comment: Ok, in which case [this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28440380/692942). You need `cmd /k` not `cmd /c`, you don’t want it to terminate after the first command is run, instead you want it to return the command prompt and execute the next command.

Comment: Now if I use `cmd /k cd C:\\Users\\Username\\myFolder & mkdir mySubfolder` mySubfolder is created in the disk D where my HTA is and I see opened command promt

Comment: It’s possible the `&` needs escaping but don't really have much experience with JScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your problem seems to be more running a program with a specific working directory than really running several commands in a the same cmd context (for wich I'd put all the commands in a cmd script and run that script from the hta), I'd suggest you to specify the working directory before you run your command :

```
<script>
var WShell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');
WShell.CurrentDirectory = 'C:\\Users\\Username\\myFolder';
WShell.run('cmd /c mkdir mySubfolder');
</script>
```